# Querying an async has Many Ember realtionship doesn't trigger any ajax request.

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

The title is self explanatory but what it's happening is that, when I go on the view route no Ajax request is made.

Moreover using the ember inspector component for chrome dev tools, in the data section, the message model has 0 items.

I've these ember versions as below:

```
DEBUG: -------------------------------
DEBUG: Ember      : 1.4.0
DEBUG: Ember Data : 1.0.0-beta.7.f87cba88
DEBUG: Handlebars : 1.3.0
DEBUG: jQuery     : 1.10.2
DEBUG: -------------------------------
```

In this code I'm using fixtures to represent the json that came back from my backend but the result is the same using fixtures or the RESTadapter.

```js
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('threads', { path: '/' }, function() {
        this.route('view', { path: ':thread_id' })
    });
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

App.ThreadsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
       return this.store.find('thread');
    }
});

App.ThreadsViewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
       return this.store.find('thread', params.thread_id).get('messages');
    }
});

App.Message = DS.Model.extend({
    body: DS.attr('string'),
    thread: DS.belongsTo('thread')
});

App.Thread = DS.Model.extend({
    messages: DS.hasMany('message')
});

App.Thread.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 7,
        messages: [1, 4, 7, 8]
    }
];

App.Message.FIXTURES = [
    {
        id: 1,
        body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, voluptas, ducimus, temporibus neque adipisci culpa veniam nostrum harum voluptates impedit similique doloribus repudiandae suscipit atque vitae quisquam dolorum libero sequi?',
        thread: 7
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, voluptas, ducimus, temporibus neque adipisci culpa veniam nostrum harum voluptates impedit similique doloribus repudiandae suscipit atque vitae quisquam dolorum libero sequi?',
        thread: 7
    },
    {
        id: 7,
        body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, voluptas, ducimus, temporibus neque adipisci culpa veniam nostrum harum voluptates impedit similique doloribus repudiandae suscipit atque vitae quisquam dolorum libero sequi?',
        thread: 7
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. A, voluptas, ducimus, temporibus neque adipisci culpa veniam nostrum harum voluptates impedit similique doloribus repudiandae suscipit atque vitae quisquam dolorum libero sequi?',
        thread: 7
    }
];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem http://emberjs.jsbin.com/taxeb/1

Comment: @CyrilFluck u're using the RestAdapter, obviously in the bin doesn't work.
if u switch to the fixture adapter u'll se what I mean try this (http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lukamuya/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixture adapter doesn't perform any XHR requests as all the data are already available in the app/page.

For the fact that you don't see any records in Ember Inspector, I've seen the problem when installing the extension through the web store if you are not using the right version of Ember and Ember Data. I don't see any problem with the following updated jsbin.

I've updated the jsbin to make it more ember idiomatic http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lukamuya/4

- In order to make your life easier with Ember, you should follow the naming conventions (`ThreadsViewRoute` is in fact `ThreadMessagesRoute`).
- Nesting resources are not implemented the way you did it. Check `this.resource('threads')` and `this.resource('thread')`.

One issue in your JsBin, is that you use ThreadsView with an ID in the url. As you don't specify the `ThreadsViewController`, Ember thinks that you will return a single object and uses `Ember.ObjectController` and not `Ember.ArrayController`. In the `model` hook for this route, you return an array of messages which confuses Ember.

The other one is that `store.find` returns a promise. You can't write

`store.find('thread', '7').get('messages')`

but instead

`store.find('thread', '7').then( function( thread) {
  return thread.get('messages');
})`

EDIT: based on your comment, I've updated the JsBin http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lukamuya/9 so that `/threads/1` shows the list of messages of the thread `1`.

Comment: It's clear that I'm very new in ember, but from what I can understand,  I can change the behavior through the controller.
My app needs to work in this way:
/:thread_id show the thread messages
/ redirect to /:thread_id based on some param

Plus I don't understand what does `return this.modelFor('thread').get('messages');` and why use this instead of the promise solution that u've suggested

ty for your time and assistence

Comment: I've added an updated JsBin to reflect your comment. No more ThreadMessages now.

Comment: That's not the desired behavior but I'll work on it! ty for the advices I'll look into ember more!

Comment: You are too kind! I think I have found the right path with http://emberjs.jsbin.com/lukamuya/10 do u think it's right with naming convention and all?